# how to add Users mobile number to Magento report filter

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, filter, reports

I have followed [inchoo post](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/comment-page-1/#comment-429849)  to create the custom report for Magento 1.9 it works perfectly.

I want to add Users mobile number to the filter list.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in _prepareCollection method :-

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
            'city'       => 'city',
            'country_id' => 'country_id',
              'telephone' => 'telephone'
        ))
```

in _prepareColumns function add below after city or where you want

```
    $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Telephone'),
        'index'  => 'telephone'
    ));
```

Comment: @jaisal is that work for you

Comment: Can you help to add purchased Product  Quantity to it ?